# WebAPI projects stopped working in Visual Studio 2012 Update 1

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Perfectly working project stopped working after I upgraded to Update 1. More frustrating is - it rebuilds perfectly. But when I try to run I get a modal msgbox with "System.Exception" in it ONLY.

[image]

Now I even tried by creating a fresh webAPI project - even that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had to uninstall VS 2012 and re-install it. I had similar issue when I tried instaling SQL 2012 Express which required VS2010 SP1 and didn't install without that. So I decided to rebuild all and now all are working.